How to efficiently enable / disable plugins while troubleshooting?
I want to be able to disable or enable a bunch of lazynvim plugins at once in my config to find one that's causing issues. I found this python script: Bisect bad plugin but can't get it work, and ideally I'd want to be able to bisect inside nvim. Are there any workflows for editing lua to do this efficiently?

What kind of trouble are you running into while trying to use the "bisect bad plugin" script? It seems it might need some editing of the script itself (to set paths correctly) and you need to add the appropriate snippet to your NeoVim config, but it sounds like it would be a good way to troubleshoot plugin issues if you have tons of plugins in your NeoVim setup
